# iPhone 4S recovery error 29

Tags: itunes, iphone, restore

My iPhone 4S keeps getting stuck on the boot logo. It has never been jailbroken. When I try to restore it in the latest version of iTunes I keep getting this:

[image: Error message 29]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It may be a hardware problem in the iPhone/ PC, or a wonky network connection. This [Apple Support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204770) may help. Do you have a new USB cable you can try? Make sure iTunes is updated on the PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as it turns out **the battery connector is damaged**. I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wOXmrFnDnQI) that explains step by step on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed the error by changing the battery. Before a week I replaced my battery, but it was a Chinese battery from ebay. This was the reason for the error. Today I just changed the battery - inserted the original battery and BOOM. The iOS 9.1 was installed on my iPhone. You should try this will work 100%.

Source: http://www.unlockboot.com/2015/10/how-to-fix-itunes-error-29-iphone-4s-5.html

Answer (score -1):

Replacing the battery method worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had a hardware problem showing error 29.Had to take the phone to a hardware engineer who fixed the chip.